# Performing filewrite using nodeJS when an event occurs in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

My need is simple. I have a complete table in a separate html file. I have a page where I have used this table using ajax call. This table is editable. Whenever I am editing this table, onInput event, I need to replace the external table file with the currently edited table. I know this is not possible with just javascript, I need server side scripting. I am trying to do this with node.js, but I have no idea how to combine this both. Do I need to write a web service in nodeJS for this? Are is there any better way to achieve this?